# one for loop wraps 2 indexof method, what is the time efficiency?

Tags: time-complexity, space-complexity, big-o-notation

I'm confused about how to know the time / space efficiency.

1. If there is an array whose size is `n`, do a for loop on this array, so that time efficiency should be O(n) = n, where n is array size. then if I have two indexof methods in the loop, indexOf and lastIndexOf, should the O(n) become n*(2n)? because each of the indexof methods has the time efficiency of n as well just like a for loop?
2. how to know the space efficiency of this method?

```
char firstNotRepeatingCharacter(String s) {

    char[] str = s.toCharArray();
    // n
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        char item = str[i];
        // 2n
        if(s.indexOf(item) == s.lastIndexOf(item)) return item;  

    }
    // 2n2

    return '_';
}
```

Comment: (There is "*depends*". On a future system not only identifying function parameter&result tuples to cache, but "*queries*" to invest preprocessing for, too.) In space analysis, there is *additional* space as well as *total*: what is your take?

Comment: Note that you can trivially about double the speed: indexOf(str[I]) is either I or an earlier index. If indexOf ≠ 0 then it is also ≠ lastIndexOf(item). You just can write "if (I == s.lastIndexOfItem()).

Comment: You can save a lot more if you have a function that is like lastIndexOf(item) but only checks the first k elements. Say you have a million elements. And item #1 has lastIndexOfItem = 7945. Then if you try to determine lastIndexOfItem (item #2) you only need to examine the first 7945 items. I bet there is more room for improvement with O(1) space.

Comment: Note that when you are given a worst case time complexity for a function, adding k values of the function can be a lot better than k times the worst case. Maybe not for indexOf.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. But time complexity we measure **only** in big-O notation.

So the code above has time complexity $\mathcal O(n^2)$

The space complexity depends on `indexof`'s space complexity. Assuming it was done with a for loop and a simple comparison, the space complexity would be $\mathcal O(log(n))$ - as the  storing the array length $n$ required $log(n)$ bits, and therefore keeping in memory the index `i` will take at most that much space.

Comment: And we often ignore the log(n) factor in practice. Even if we didn't ignore it, the array takes n x some size which is a lot more.